# changing 127.0.1.1 back to 127.0.0.1 -- will it break anything in Unity?

Tags: unity, networking, hostname

The  `/etc/hosts` file defaults your hostname to `127.0.1.1` rather than `127.0.0.1`

```
127.0.0.1   localhost 
127.0.1.1   my_machine
```

I've already found out [**why**](http://www.leonardoborda.com/blog/127-0-1-1-ubuntu-debian/). But that was giving me problems testing some web apps, which had hard-coded assumption, that local machine == `127.0.0.1`. So I've change my hosts file to

```
127.0.0.1   localhost my_machine
```

Question is:

- are there reasons for which `127.0.1.1` hack still valid?
- if so, which software included in 11.04 might have problem with the change I've made?

Answer (score 11):

Your local machine **IS** `127.0.0.1`. It's the standard IP for the `localhost`.

Instead, the **hostname** of your machine resolves to `127.0.1.1`.

It should be no problem to change it to anything in the range 127.0.0.0/8 which is reserved for *loopbacks*.

As long as nothing listens **exclusively** on `127.0.1.1` you should be safe.
To find if there's something listening on `127.0.1.1`:

```
sudo netstat -tunelp | grep 127.0.1.1
```